# SSRS Tablix Row Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a tablix and hierarchical grouping in the tablix.

For example:

```
Gender------%count       
Female------ 10  
Male -------  0
```

My query returns all records with Female since there are no records with Male it returns nothing For Male.

In the report I want to show Male as 0 but I am not able to... How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typically two options in this situation.

**Report Level**

Instead of having dynamic group header rows or detail rows, you create a table with three table header rows - one for the column headers and one each for `Male` and `Female`.

Then you can fill the row values with appropriate conditional expressions, e.g. for `Male` row total use something like:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Gender.Value = "Male", 1, 0)
```

This will give you `0` instead of `Nothing` even if there are no `Male` values in the Dataset.

**Database level**

The other option is to change the Dataset to always return an aggregated row for each gender, i.e. if you're getting the data from a T-SQL query you'd use something like:

```
select * from
(
  select Gender = 'Male'
  union
  select Gender = 'Female'
) Gender
```

as the base table (typically you won't have a `Gender` table, hence the query above) and `LEFT JOIN` it to all the required value data, i.e. always returning each gender row even if no values exist. This way you could still normal group/detail rows to display the data.